# What would be the German expressions to represent the expand and collapse actions on a collapse/expand UI menu?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

If a website has a expand/collapse menu. How can I say the expand / collapse actions in German.

When it's collapsed, I would like to say: **"expand"**, **"see more"** or something similar.

When it's expanded, I would like to say: **"collapse"**, **"see less"** or something similar.

What would be the correct expressions to use in that scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- "expand": maximieren, ausklappen, vergrößern, erweitern
- "see more": mehr anzeigen (Anzeigen),
- "collapse": minimieren, einklappen, verkleinern, verringern
- "see less": weniger anzeigen (Anzeigen),

Comment: Note that computer UI commands generally use bare infinitives, in other words an infinitive with no subject or finite verb. For more complex prompts, these would be placed at the end since that's where infinitive verbs normally go.

Comment: *aufklappen* and *zuklappen* would also work.

Comment: "Vergrößern/verkleinern" finde ich unpassend - da würde ich eine größere Schrift vermuten. Bei einem großen "Anzeigen" erwarte ich Ads, Spam oder vermute, dass die Seite/der Bereich bezahlte Werbung ist. "Mehr Anzeigen" wäre demnach der Ruf nach mehr Werbung. "anzeigen/verbergen" ginge noch. Ausklappen und einklappen wäre meine erste Wahl. Für Ausklappen würde auch "(mehr) Details" gehen, für einklappen fällt mir spontan nur "weniger Details" ein.

Answer (score 2):

As a web developer myself, the phrases *mehr anzeigen* and *weniger anzeigen* are quite common. It depends on the item being expanded, but for menus thats a rather uncommon thing to label. From a user friendly perspective, it often makes sense to name the thing youre expanding:

- Menü anzeigen
- Alle Filter anzeigen
- Weniger Filter
- Zur Übersicht
- mehr anzeigen
- Liste einklappen